# select/highlight text ios

Tags: ios

In iOS 5 you can hold your finger on text and you can select/highlight text and it will bring up a popup menu. I'd like to implement that same functionality for an application I am developing. It doesn't seem like there is any easy way to do that. Can anyone refer me to a tutorial & example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty much a default behavior. Make sure that you have this in your code:

```
myTextView.userInteractionEnabled = YES
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work for me. I am opening a PDF much like in this example:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Listings/Classes_PDFScrollView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281-Classes_PDFScrollView_m-DontLinkElementID_4

I'd like to select/highlight the text in the pdf.

Comment: That won't help. Apple has added those features into iOS5, but there's no API. Either use UIWebView or roll your own solution. (I wrote about a year on my own framework to do this - http://is.gd/irvxfL)